# Comma separated string into multiple arrays separated by comma using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How to convert comma separated string into multiple array strings separated by comma

```js
var data = "34,2,76",
    result = data.split(',').map(s => s.split(',')).slice(0);
    
console.log(result);
```

The result is `[ ["34"], ["2"], ["76"] ]`.

How to get the output exactly as below as a string?

```
[ myarray.values[34], myarray.values[2], myarray.values[76] ]
```

Notice that I do not have double quotes and each array has a name. Also we do not know how many comma separated values will be passed.

I use react and some ES6 cool way will be even better.

Comment: `data.split(',')` is enough for your answer. Which returns `['34', '2', '76']`

Comment: What is `myarray` and `myarray.values`?

Comment: If I understand, this should work: `data.split(',').map(i => myarray.values[i])`

Comment: @hev1 That is the format autocomplete in material ui expects. My values are stored in a separate array and for example, I am calling it myarray.values. I want to get to the nth elements of that array based on what is passed in string separated by comma

Comment: @hurricane I know how to datasplit. You probably did not want to read my question fully

Comment: @hurricane Please do not accuse others of downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` on the comma and then `map` each part using template literal interpolation and then join on the comma, prepending a opening square bracket and appending a closing square bracket to the result.

```js
const data = "34,2,76";
const res = '[' + data.split(',').map(x => `myarray.values[${x}]`).join(',') + ']';
console.log(res);
```

Comment: The output is   [
  9,
  "199",
  "something"
]

Comment: @Kal Yes, were you expected something different?

Comment: Yes. from my question `[ myarray.values[34], myarray.values[2], myarray.values[76] ]`

Comment: @Kal That's what hev1's answer gives you

Comment: @Kal This does exactly that: it obtains the value at each index. Did you want string literals to be returned instead?

Comment: @hev1 I see what you guys are saying. Yes it returns the values but I need to format it exactly like - `[ myarray.values[34], myarray.values[2], myarray.values[76] ]` to supply in props to a material ui component.

Comment: @Kal So you want it as a string?

Comment: yes a string that says - `[ myarray.values[34], myarray.values[2], myarray.values[76] ]`.  I will update my question to make that clear

Comment: @hev1 Yes, I see how you did it. thats the answer.

Comment: @Kal Happy to help.

Comment: @hev1 Thanks much !